# Excel - How can I populate sheet1 with corresponding data from sheet2

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I'm not really sure how to go about this. I want to populate Sheet1 with the corresponding refid from sheet2 when there is a match on id column:

Sheet2 only has 1 entry for each id and unique corresponding refid. Sheet1 may have mulitple entries for a given id

**Sheet1:**

[image]

**Sheet2:**

[image: Sheet2]

An explanation of how I could carry out an operation like this either as a formula or through vba would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following formula in cell B2 in Sheet 1 and copy it down:

```
  =vlookup(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$7,2,0)
```

It is not necessary for the values in Sheet 2 to be sorted by the id column.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer but the second paramater is giving an error. I have had a look at the vlookup function and the only bit I am slightly confused about are the dollar signs in the second argument. I can see what the second argument is doing but why do I need the dollar signs what do they mean? I notice it doesnt work without them either

Comment: Ok, I got it working with this: =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:Sheet2!$B$7,2,FALSE), If you could explain what the dollars mean though I would be most grateful

Comment: The dollar signs anchor the reference so that it does not change when you copy the formula to another cell. Without the dollar signs, if you copied the formula to, say, B3, it would change to =VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet2!A3:B8,2,0), which you would not want.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've got a chance of applying it to the actual data set now. cheers